# How to pass typecript variable to aria-label

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wai-aria

how to pass a typecript variable to aria-label ?

follow code:

```
//function that returns the user's browser language.

private setLiterals(): void {
    const lang = this.languageService.getShortLanguage();

    if (lang in poRichTextLiteralsDefault) {
      this.ariaLabel = poRichTextLiteralsDefault[lang].textColor;
    }
  }
```

```
<input
          aria-label="????"
/>
```

Comment: an "special" attribute you must use `[attr.your-attribute]="variable"`, e.g. `<input [attr.aria-label]="ariaLabel">`

Comment: @Eliseo is right, any aria-* attribute that you want to set dynamically you need [attr.aria-*]="value"